# NxN diagonal matrix with mixed zero and nonzero diagonal elements

Tags: matrix, function-construction

I'd like to make a function that takes an odd integer N and returns a diagonal matrix A with the odd diagonal elements $A_{11}$, $A_{33}$, etc. equal to zero and the even diagonal elements $A_{22}$, $A_{44}$, etc. equal to one. The best idea I've come up with is to use ReplacePart on a (NxN) constant array. I had hoped that the following would do the job:

```
A[N_]:= ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0,{N,N}],{2 i_,2 i_}->1]
```

but it seems like {2 i_,2 i_} is not a recognisable pattern (unlike if I were to put in {i_,i_} it would replace *all* diagonal elements with ones).

Comment: Please do not use `N` as a variable. `N` is a built-in function in Mathematica. In general, avoid naming your own variables or functions using names that start with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will use n henceforth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n = 9;
ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {n, n}], {i_?EvenQ, i_?EvenQ} -> 1]
% // MatrixForm
```

Or

```
Clear["`*"];
n = 9;
M = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} /; Mod[i, 2] == 0 -> 1}, {n, n}];
M // Normal // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Your `SparseArray` solution can be written more simply as `SparseArray[{i_?EvenQ, i_} -> 1, n]`.

Comment: @C.E. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:

```
diagonalMatrix[n_] := DiagonalMatrix@PadRight[{}, n, {0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Mod[DiagonalMatrix[Range[#] - 1], 2] & @ 7

Boole @ Array[EvenQ@# && # == #2 &, {#, #}] & @ 7

SparseArray[Band[{2, 2}, {#, #}, {2, 2}] -> 1] & @ 7

SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> Mod[i + 1, 2], {#, #}] & @ 7

MapAt[0 # &, IdentityMatrix@#, {;; , ;; ;; 2}] & @ 7

MapIndexed[Mod[#2[[1]] + 1, 2] # &]@ IdentityMatrix[#] & @ 7

ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix@#, {i_, i_} :> Mod[i + 1, 2]] & @ 7
```

all give

```
% // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 2):

This maybe easier to understand?

```
Table[Boole[OddQ@i && OddQ@j && i == j], {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}]
```